# How can I use HadoopFileSystem to read from s3a:// paths?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a Beam job running on Spark that reads data from S3. I have tried using the [S3FileSystem](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services2/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws2/s3/S3FileSystem.java) to read an s3:// path directly, but found this to be much slower than when I use s3a:// via HDFS in a non-Beam job. I believe it should be possible to read s3a:// paths using the [HadoopFileSystem](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/hadoop-file-system/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hdfs/HadoopFileSystem.java), but I can't seem to get this working.

If I include the org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-hadoop-file-system dependency, I still see this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No filesystem found for scheme s3a
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:515)
```

This is in an environment where I know the org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws dependency is already included (AWS EMR), and s3a:// paths work out-of-the-box with a plain Spark job. To be safe, I tried also including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws and org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client directly, as recommended in the [Hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Getting_Started), but that still gave the same errors as above and below.

From looking at the [HadoopFileSystemRegistrar](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/hadoop-file-system/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hdfs/HadoopFileSystemRegistrar.java), it looks like the only way to register a custom scheme (i.e. s3a:// in this case) is to use an option like --hdfsConfiguration=[{"fs.default.name":"s3a://{bucket_path}"}] to get the scheme registered, but this still results in an error:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3a"
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone managed to make reads from s3a:// paths work?

Comment: If I recall correctly, EMR has a forked version of the hadoop-aws package and uses s3n or s3 prefix in place of s3a. There's a thread pool size config in the S3 Filesystem class, by the way, did you try increasing it for speed?